# How does Automapper work from a nested model to a flat model?

Tags: model-view-controller, dns, nested, automapper

I have a nested view model similar to this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{      
    //...

    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }

    public AddressViewModel{ get; set; }
}
```

The AddressViewModel looks like this:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
     public string Street {get; set;}
     public string City {get; set;}
     public string State {get; set;}
     public string Zip {get; set;}
}
```

Then, there's an Employee domain object like so:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map the EmployeeViewModel to the Employee domain object. This is what I came up with and it works, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>().ForMember(destination => destination.Street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressViewModel.Street))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressViewModel.City))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressViewModel.State))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Zip, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressViewModel.Zip));
```

As you can see, the property names in the Employee domain object and the AddressViewModel are the same. So, it seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout the [flattening sample](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening&referringTitle=Home) in the documentation. And here's an example:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{      
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>();
        var result = Mapper.Map<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>(new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            EmployeeFirstName = "first name",
            Address = new AddressViewModel
            {
                Street = "some street"
            }
        });
        Console.WriteLine(result.EmployeeFirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(result.AddressStreet);
    }
}
```

Notice how for the flattening to work out of the box the target property is called `AddressStreet`.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Perfect fit. I did not know how it worked, and it solved a similar problem I was having too.